# How to update NiFi template flow for a newer NiFi build?

Tags: apache-nifi

If I created a NiFi flow template in NiFi v1.11.1, what is the best way to update that template flow for a newer NiFi build version say v1.15.0?

The XML template file has several processors referencing v1.11.1 and when loading it in v1.15.0, it is sometimes unable to load.

Do I need to re-construct this flow template in the newer NiFi build or should I manually modify the XML template file?

Comment: How you supposed to know what to change in the template XML file! Chances that this will corrupt the XML file.. When you add template on v1.15 then whatever is not supported will get grayed out (kind of disabled), and then you can replace/modify only those items.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to start manually changing the template XML.

Update NiFi and your flow will update with it.

If things have changed, e.g. a processor has a new, required property, it will be left in an Invalid state with a warning tip that tells you that you need to add the missing property.